# PHP array function that matches this foreach loop

Tags: php

PHP have all sort of built in array functions. 
So I'm wondering if there is a function that is equivalent to the foreach loop in this code.

```
$args = array('var1', 'var2');
$args2 = array('var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6');

foreach ($args2 as $arg) {
    $args[] = $arg;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**.

> ```
> array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
> ```
>
> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

With `array_merge` function.
But note that numeric keys will be renumbered!

Or you can use union operator: *if keys will be set

```
$array1 = array('key1' => 'zero_a', 'key2' => 'two_a', 'key3' => 'three_a');
$array2 = array('key4' => 'one_b', 'key5' => 'three_b', 'key6' => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
```

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Union operator won't work for example in op, array_merge is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

array_merge function is used for merging multiple arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php